# What is the best way showing Folders' content using Xamarin iOS in C#?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview

I am developing an app using Xamarin.iOS in C# language. My tableview retrieves list from webservice. This list contains folders and files. and folders can have also children and maybe children also have their own children..

So to display files, I use webview, its OK but for folders, what should I do? There can be many subfolders, I am thinking to use 2 tableviews and one webview

First tableview is for showing first list
Second tableview will show the folder's content, can be some subfolders and files. If the file tapped, webview will display it, if folder tapped, then I should reload the list of tablewView..

Logically its OK but what about if user push back.. How I should get back previous list, I dont want to call it from webservice again.. I am asking what can be the best model for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody will not reply my question. Well I would like to share my solution..

I called the tableview in the same tablewView. First of All, I entered a storyboard id for the tableview controller name is commonstoryboard so after my code is like that

```
var item = (profileLists[indexPath.Row] as QuickSearchProfile);
var result =  search.GetQuickSearchProfile(item);
        //    FillTable(result);
          //  TableView.ReloadData();

var controller = (CommonTableView)this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("commonstoryboard");
var commonTableView = new CommonTableView(controller.Handle);
commonTableView.profileLists.AddRange(result);
NavigationController.PushViewController(commonTableView, true);
```

so everything works how i want. I can go many subfolders and can back (previous views still have the old values, so in this case,i do not need to call again any list from web service) I really didnt expect that kind of solution but it became perfect !!